# Oracle DBMS_DEBUG.GET_VALUE can't get variable values when debugging large packages

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I try to debug some function in PL\SQL. When I debug large package (package body contains 21666 lines of code), I can't see variable values, I always get (Not a variable).

I added debug information.

When debuging smaller packages this problem don't ocures.

This is part of PL\SQL Developer debug log:

```
begin
  handle.owner := :package_owner;
  handle.name  := :package_name;

  if :inbody = 1 then
     handle.namespace := sys.dbms_debug.namespace_pkg_body;
  else
     handle.namespace := sys.dbms_debug.namespace_pkgspec_or_toplevel;
  end if;  
  
  :result := sys.dbms_debug.get_value(variable_name => :variable_name,
                                      handle => handle,
                                      scalar_value => :scalar_value,
                                      format => :format);
  if :result = 16 then :result := 3; end if;
end;
             
:RESULT = 3
:VARIABLE_NAME = requisition_no_
:SCALAR_VALUE = Null
:FORMAT = Null
:PACKAGE_OWNER = USER
:PACKAGE_NAME = PURCHASE_API
:INBODY = 1
```

```
error_no_such_object  CONSTANT binary_integer :=  3;  -- no such var/parm
error_bad_handle      CONSTANT binary_integer := 16;  -- can't set bpt there
```

Anyone knows how to fix that ?
Maybe there is some Oracle Server configuration telling how large package body can be to have variable values on stack.